# Why does sudo -S prevent an interactive shell

Tags: shell, sudo

I'm trying to switch to another user using sudo, but when I use the `-S` option to read the password from stdin I'm returned back to my original user.

e.g.

Contents of `~newuser/.profile`:

```
echo "Welcome to newuser's account"
```

Using sudo without `-S`:

```
$ whoami
origuser
$ sudo -iu newuser
[sudo] password for origuser:
Welcome to newuser's account
$ whoami
newuser
```

But when using `-S`:

```
$ whoami
origuser
$ sudo -Siu newuser < password.txt
Welcome to newuser's account
$ whoami
origuser
```

So, as you can see, using `-S` causes the shell to be invoked and the `.profile` parsed, but then the shell drops back to the original user.

Why is this?

Is it possible to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sudo -Siu newuser < password.txt`, standard input for the command `sudo -Siu newuser` is taken from `password.txt`. The `-S` option causes `sudo` to read the password from standard input, and thus from `password.txt`. **But standard input for the ensuing shell remains redirected.**

When input is redirected to a shell--whether or not it is running in interactive mode--and end of input is reached, the shell quits. This is similar to running a script and having it reach the end of the file, or to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to cause your terminal to indicate end-of-input.

Therefore, you are starting a shell whose input is redirected from a file, whose contents are probably already mostly read. It reaches the end and quits. Really, your goal is for the shell you start with `sudo` to take input from your terminal, and not from that file.

Although you can probably work around this with additional file descriptors and more indirection, as well as other methods, **I suggest you simply perform the authentication as a separate step first**, before running the shell:

```
sudo -Sv < password.txt
```

Having done that, you can just run:

```
sudo -iu newuser
```

If you run the second command shortly after the first, then your timestamp will still be valid and you will not need to enter a password at all.

Note that, when you run a command as a named user with `sudo` with `-u`, it works the same as when you run a command as root (which is typically done without `-u`). The password it asks you for is *your password*, not that of the target user, which is why the command that just does authentication (with `-v`) does not mention the other user. It is *possible* to configure `sudo` to expect the target user's password instead, but people rarely do that in practice and you have not mentioned it, so I assume that's not what you (and most other readers) are interested in.

(Of course, the usual caveats about security risks associated with reading the password in from a file like this continue to apply, to the same degree they applied before.)

Comment: Many thanks!  This is spot-on for my needs.  I missed the -v on the man page and I think the description of -S is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

When a shell is run with its standard input connected to something other than a terminal, it reads commands from standard input and executes them, until standard input is closed.

When you run

```
sudo -Siu newuser < password.txt
```

`sudo`’s standard input reads from `password.txt`; `sudo` doesn’t change that before starting the shell, so the shell also reads from `password.txt`. Two things can happen then: if `sudo` needed a password, it will have read it, and the shell will immediately reach the end of the file (assuming it contains nothing else) and exit; otherwise, the shell will attempt to parse the password and execute it...

I’m not sure there’s a reliable way round this, and in any case, the dual handling means you probably don’t want to (unless you’ve disabled tokens). You *can* prepare a token before starting a shell, as described in [Eliah Kagan’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435974/86440), if you’ve not disabled tokens.

Comment: Making the second line of the file `exec /bin/bash < /dev/tty` should do the trick.

Comment: @psusi only if the first line is consumed by `sudo`...